# Assert ElementNotPresent Webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, assert

Can I assert an element that is not present? I want to assert that the element "textarea" is not present on the site.

```
try {
    assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("textarea")));
} catch (Error e) {
    verificationErrors.append(e.toString());
    System.out.println(verificationErrors);
}


private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
    try {
        driver.findElement(by);
        return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: the code you posted does not serve the purpose for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Method #1**

> import junit.framework.Assert;
>
> if(!isElementPresent(By.cssSelector("textarea")))
> {
> System.out.println("Text Not Available");
> } else
> {
> Assert.fail();
> }

---

**Method #2**

In your case, please go with negative use case given below

## positive case

> import junit.framework.Assert;
>
> boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("your text");
> Assert.assertTrue(b);

## negative case

> import junit.framework.Assert;
>
> boolean b = driver.getPageSource().contains("your text");
> Assert.assertFalse(b);

There are numerous ways to do this. The above is few :)

Method #1 is highly suggested!

Comment: let me know if you have questions

Comment: Searching through the page source is an incredibly bad and inaccurate way to look for an element. Please rethink this answer.

Comment: @jimEvans I have seen your contribution to Selenium. Really great to know this.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your question ought to work.

Another method is to call [`driver.findElements`](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#findElements%28org.openqa.selenium.By%29) instead of `driver.findElement` (note the added `s`). Instead of throwing a `NoSuchElementException`, `driver.findElements` will return an empty list if there are no matches. From there, you just have to assert that the size of the returned list is zero.